# JPA + StoredProcedureCall + object type IN parameter

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I'm trying to do a simple thing: call stored procedure which have a object type parameter.

This is what I have in db:

```
create or replace
TYPE TEST_TYPE AS OBJECT 
(
  test_field varchar(100)
)
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC 
(
  PARAM1 IN TEST_TYPE 
) AS 
BEGIN
END TEST_PROC;
```

This is what I have in my java code:

```
@Embeddable
@Struct(name = "TEST_TYPE", fields = {"TEST_FIELD"})
public class TestStruct
{

    private String testField;

    public String getTestField() {
        return testField;
    }

    public void setTestField(String testField) {
        this.testField = testField;
    }
}
```

and

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {

        StoredProcedureCall call = new StoredProcedureCall();
        call.setProcedureName("TEST_PROC");
        call.addNamedArgument("PARAM1", "PARAM1", Types.STRUCT, "TEST_TYPE", TestStruct.class);

        DataReadQuery dataReadQuery = new DataReadQuery(call);
        dataReadQuery.addArgument("PARAM1");

        TestStruct testStruct = new TestStruct();
        List args = new ArrayList();
        args.add(testStruct);

        Object result = ((EntityManagerImpl)em.getDelegate()).getSession().executeQuery(dataReadQuery,args);
    }
```

this is what I get in runtime:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
Error Code: 17004
Call: BEGIN TEST_PROC(PARAM1=>?); END;
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: DataReadQuery()
```

I think I totally don't understand the subject of usage structs with JPA

please help me, good people :)

What is the shortest way to make this working?

Answer (score 1):

Please send complete your code.
For call stored procedures using Spring, you have to extends StoredProcedure class. If you send your complete code, I can help better. sample pseudo code:

```
class CustomStoredProcedure extends org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure
{
    CustomStoredProcedure()
    {
        super([your-data-source], [package-name]);  
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter([your-struct-name]), Types.STRUCT));
        compile();
    }

    Map<String, Object> execute([your-parameter])
    {
        return super.execute(inputs);
    }
}
```

for better help, you have  explain complete situation.

Comment: this is complete situation - I'm just testing how to solve common problems with EclipseLink JPA2.0 implementation. BTW AFAIK Spring does not implement JPA - am I wrong?

Comment: You say correct,Spring dosn't implement JPA. I don't use EclipseLink. My solution is independent of jpa implementation, it provided by spring framework and work correct. If you want using EclipseLink only, you have to read its documents.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.

Ensure that the descriptor was defined for the struct.  (i.e. session.getDescrptor(TestStruct.class))

Can you call stored procedures with other types?

What database are you using, have you set your platform correctly to Oracle?

Comment: "Ensure that the descriptor was defined for the struct" does it mean that descriptor will be created automatically due to annotations? Recently I'v tried to set them manualy:`            ObjectRelationalDataTypeDescriptor d = new ObjectRelationalDataTypeDescriptor();
d.setJavaClass(TestStruct.class);
d.descriptorIsAggregate();
d.setStructureName("TEST_TYPE");
d.addDirectMapping("TEST_FIELD", "getTestField", "setTestField", "testField");
d.setShouldOrderMappings(false);
((EntityManagerImpl)em.getDelegate()).getServerSession().addDescriptor(d);
`

Comment: I can call stored procedures with simple types like varchar. I am using Oracle 10 and proper jdbc drivers.

Comment: The descriptor should be create from the annotations, but if you did not specific the class in your persistence.xml or had other issues it may not, so checking it is there would be a good idea.  Did it work when you defined it in code?

Comment: no, it did not. My colleague tell me that he found some bugs in EclipseLink libraries which we used

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [eclipselink](/questions/tagged/eclipselink) skips descriptors for the `@Struct` and `@Embeddable` annotated classes unless they are referenced by some other class. The shortest way to make it working is to use workaround based on this assumption. Put additional class in the jar where your `META-INF/persistence.xml` is located:

```
@Entity
public class StructEntitiesWorkaround {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private TestStruct testStruct;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `SimpleJdbcCall` with `Types.STRUCT`.

Here is an example: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html